# Inconsistent Ownership

Tags: c++11, ownership

I have a class that up until this point had a reference to another class because it didn't own that class and was not responsible for managing it's memory.

```
class MyClass
{
    OtherClass& m_other;
public:
    MyClass( OtherClass& other ) : m_other( other ) {}
};
```

I am however in a situation where in some cases `MyClass` is the owner of m_other and I'd like a deletion to lead to the deletion `OtherClass`. And in some cases it isn't the owner.

In this instance, is it more appropriate to have two classes to represent both cases or to have a single class that encapsulates both cases (with a unique_ptr). e.g.

```
class MyClassRef
{
    OtherClass& m_other;
public
    MyClassRef( OtherClass& other ) : m_other( other ) {}
};

class MyClassOwner
{
    std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> m_other; // Never null
public:
    MyClassOwner( std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> other ) : m_other( std::move( other ) ) {}
};
```

vs

```
class MyClass
{
    OtherClass& m_other; // class may or may not be the one we manage.
    std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> m_managed; // May be null
public:
    MyClass( std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> managed ) : m_other( *managed ), m_managed( std::move( m_managed ) ) {}
    MyClass( OtherClass& other ) : m_other( other ), m_managed() {}
};
```

This is probably a rather simple example, but in general when dealing with split cases is it better to create new classes to handle these cases... or to encapsulate as many cases in a single class - to a reasonable level.

Edit: A third option which is similar to the second option is to use `std::shared_ptr<T>` e.g.

```
class MyClass
{
    std::shared_ptr<OtherClass> m_other;
public:
    MyClass( std::shared_ptr<OtherClass> other) : m_other( other ) {}
    MyClass( OtherClass& other ) : m_other( std::shared_ptr<OtherClass>( &other, []( OtherClass* p ){} ) ) {}
};
```

Note that I want `MyClass` to still accept references as to allow pointers to stack-allocated objects; this is why the constructor creates a `shared_ptr<OtherClass>` with a custom deleter not to delete the stack object.

Comment: If you go for the split-class option, then you have to create a lot of overloaded functionality to be able to handle both types.

Comment: A fourth option: double check your design. Provided details doesn't allow us to help here, but it's rather unusual design and so worth to check if it's a good one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the class may be an owner in some cases, while in some other cases it is not an owner, you should use `std::shared_ptr<T>`, which maintains *use count*, in place of `std::unique_ptr<T>`, which requires unique ownership of the resource.

As long as all references to the object pointed to by `m_other` are maintained through `std::shared_ptr<T>` smart pointers, resource management would be automated for you, regardless of the part of the program that owns the object.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is satisfying. The semantics of `std::shared_pt<T>`, as best as I've understood it, is that I (`MyClass`) am a definite owner of this object - but someone else might own it as well. What i'm defining is a case where I might or might not own this object. And specifically in my case, the object I have a reference to is a stack allocated object which doesn't form well with a smart pointer - I know I can use a custom deleter to not delete the object, but that seems error prone.

Comment: @JacobHull In this case you cannot use a shared pointer, because they do not work with stack objects. There are at least two approaches here: (1) switching away from using stack objects: performance difference should be too small to measure, while automated resource management would let you deal with ownership automatically, or (2) roll your own ownership management code - pass a pointer and a `bool` to the constructor, indicating if the dependent is owned or not, and deleting owned objects in the destructor.